# django import export app error: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm upgrading a Django site to 3.1.2 and noticed one backend app wasn't working, in the process of asking the [community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888716/django-guideresource-object-has-no-attribute-meta?noredirect=1#comment114724143_64888716) help in fixing this I found out the app wasn't a custom made code by a single coder for the site but a community project called [django-import-export](https://pypi.org/project/django-import-export/). Since it's up to date and supports django 3.1 i deleted the manual way it was setup as a folder and pip installed it. i then tried to do a `makemigrations` threw an error and after reading the setup docs assumed possibly you need to do `collectstatic` first, it also threw the same error

```
(kpsga) sammy@kpsga:~/webapps/kpsga$ python manage.py collectstatic
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/sammy/webapps/kpsga/guides/models.py", line 77, in <module>
    class GuideResource(resources.ModelResource):
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 930, in __new__
    field = new_class.field_from_django_field(f.name, f,
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 1079, in field_from_django_field
    FieldWidget = cls.widget_from_django_field(django_field)
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 1045, in widget_from_django_field
    result = getattr(cls, result)(f)
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 1025, in get_fk_widget
    model=get_related_model(field))
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 49, in get_related_model
    if hasattr(field, 'related_model'):
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 95, in related_model
    apps.check_models_ready()
File "/home/sammy/webapps/envs/kpsga/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 141, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

this somehow is related to `installed_apps` so I've included the entire list below

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #site apps
    'guides',
    'pages',

    #imported old dependencies
    'blog',
    'import_export',
    'generic',

    #imports
    'comments_moderation',
    'django_comments',
    'sorl.thumbnail',

    #additional django
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
]
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but maybe it could be related to signals, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081783/django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet-file-init

Comment: check your models and ref like: 

from django.apps import AppConfig


class ShareConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'models.share'


Then in settings add full path to models eg: 'models.common.apps.CommonConfig'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traceback shows that the error occurs when loading `GuideResource` in your `models.py`.

The [getting started docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#creating-import-export-resource) for django-import-export suggest putting the resource in the `admin.py`, so I would try moving the `GuideResource` outside of `models.py`.